# Row-wise count group by variables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have the below query -

```
SELECT
  P.PRODUCT_NUMBER, 
  P.PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION, 
  SUM(S.NET_AMOUNT), 
  ROUND(STDDEV(S.NET_AMOUNT),2) AS STD_DEV  
--(SELECT COUNT OF NET_AMOUNT < = 1$ FROM PFI_FACT_SALES GROUPED BY THE SAME P.PRODUCT_NUMBER) AS CNT
    FROM PFI_DIM_PRODUCT P
    JOIN PFI_FACT_SALES S
    ON P.PRODUCT_PK_ID = S.PRODUCT_PK_ID
    WHERE P.PRODUCT_NUMBER = 'ABC'
      GROUP BY P.PRODUCT_NUMBER, P.PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION;
```

This is the part I am not able to figure out -

```
(SELECT COUNT OF NET_AMOUNT < = 1$ FROM PFI_FACT_SALES GROUPED BY THE SAME P.PRODUCT_NUMBER) AS CNT
```

What would be the best way to get the necessary row level data group by product number & product description?

Thanks.

Comment: sql-server <> oracle. I assume you must be using Oracle since STDDEV is not a built in function for sql server. The standard deviation function has 2 D's in Oracle but only 1 in sql server.

Comment: @SeanLange - Yes I am using Oracle. You are right.

Comment: That's too bad...I could help you with sql-server using count() over(partition by...) but no clue if Oracle does that or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT P.PRODUCT_NUMBER, P.PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION, SUM(S.NET_AMOUNT), 
       ROUND(STDDEV(S.NET_AMOUNT), 2) AS STD_DEV  ,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM PFI_FACT_SALES s2
        WHERE s2.PRODUCT_PK_ID = s.PRODUCT_PK_ID AND
              NET_AMOUNT <= 1
       ) as CNT
FROM PFI_DIM_PRODUCT P JOIN
     PFI_FACT_SALES S
     ON P.PRODUCT_PK_ID = S.PRODUCT_PK_ID
WHERE P.PRODUCT_NUMBER = 'ABC'
GROUP BY P.PRODUCT_NUMBER, P.PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION;
```

I'm pretty sure that you can also do this with a conditional windowed sum:

```
SELECT P.PRODUCT_NUMBER, P.PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION, SUM(S.NET_AMOUNT), 
       ROUND(STDDEV(S.NET_AMOUNT), 2) AS STD_DEV,
       SUM(CASE WHEN NET_AMOUNT <= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY s.PRODUCT_PK_ID) as CNT
FROM PFI_DIM_PRODUCT P JOIN
     PFI_FACT_SALES S
     ON P.PRODUCT_PK_ID = S.PRODUCT_PK_ID
WHERE P.PRODUCT_NUMBER = 'ABC'
GROUP BY P.PRODUCT_NUMBER, P.PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION;
```